# if $ab=e$ Then $ba=e$ and $b=a^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ by a group and let $e$ be it's identity element, and let $a\in G$ Prove:

1.If $aa=a$ then $a=e$

2.If $b\in G$ such that $ab=e$ then $ba=e$ and $b=a^{-1}$

Proof:

1. $$aa=a$$

$G$ is a group then there is $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $a^{-1}a=aa^{-1}=e$

$$a^{-1}aa=a^{-1}a\iff a^{-1}aa=e$$

Now, $G$ is a group then operation is associative, for every $a,b,c\in G: (ab)c=a(bc)$

$$\begin{align}
a^{-1}(aa)=e&\iff (a^{-1}a)a=e\\
&\iff ea=e\\
&\iff a=e.
\end{align}$$

2.

$$ab=e$$

$$\begin{align}
a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}e &\iff a^{-1}(ab)=a^{-1}\\
&\iff (a^{-1}a)b=a^{-1} \\
&\iff eb=a^{-1}\\
&\iff b=a^{-1},
\end{align}$$

$$ab=e,$$

$$\begin{align}
abab=ab&\iff a^{-1}abab=a^{-1}ab\\
&\iff bab=b\\
&\iff bab^{-1}=bb^{-1}\\
&\iff ba=a.
\end{align}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: The last line should read $\ldots\iff ba=e$, otherwise it looks correct!

Comment: Since the very beginning of 1 it may be worth noticing that $aa=a \Rightarrow a^{-1}aa=a^{-1}a$ because group operation is by definition *a map*.

Comment: This is correct but much longer than it needs to be. For example, in part 2, once you know $b=a^{-1}$ you can conclude $ba=e$ immediately without such a long argument.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly:

$$ab=e\iff a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}e\iff b=a^{-1}$$

and

$$ab=e\iff baba=bea\iff (ba)(ba)=ba\iff ba=e,$$ using the first result with $ba$.

Answer (score 0):

1. If we denote by $u$ *an* inverse of $a$ (we still don't know whether this is unique, so I find "$a^{-1}$" somehow misleading at this stage), and recall that group operation is *a map*, we get:

$$aa=a \Rightarrow (aa)u=au=e \Rightarrow a(au)=e \Rightarrow ae=a=e$$

2. $ab=e$ is precisely the *definition* of inverse of $a$, so $b=a^{-1}$ is just a (smart indeed, in hindsight) notation for this element once you have proved that it is unique.